# Como puedo leer un arraylist que yo mismo guarde en firestore de firebase desde kotlin

Tags: kotlin, hashmap

Puedo recuperar el valor o mapa, pero no puedo trabajar con el.
Guardo un mapa que contiene un `listaCarrito = arraylist<carrito>()` :

```
 var datos=mapOf(
            "fecha" to FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            "idMovimiento" to listaCarrito
        )
        Toast.makeText(this, "boton prueba", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        db.collection("prueba2").document("we").set(datos)
```

En firestore se ve así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para recuperar esa información hago lo siguiente:

```
db.collection("prueba2").document("we").get().addOnSuccessListener {
val dato = it.get("idMovimiento") as ArrayList<carrito>

println("$dato")
}

consola = [{marca=cristalina, precio=1156, total=1156, vendedor=, color=blanco/negro, categoria=conjunto, talle=85, imagen=https://www.besol.com.ar/assets/images/products_ls/d67ae69c6d744f3e8c2f5ae87d78bcda.jpg, cantidad=1, id=415, title=Conjunto sin Taza Soft de Algodón y Lycra Combinado en Contra Tono con Tanga Less}]
```

Hasta ahí perfecto. El problema viene cuando quiero acceder a alguno de esos datos.

si pongo dato.get(0), dato[0].marca, dato[0], o dato.marca
me arroja error o algo parecido a esto: "java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String"

No entiendo muy bien como funciona. Yo lo único que quiero es poder acceder a esos datos. que los veo pero no encuentro la forma de usarlos por separados.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución:
Las objetos se guardan como mapas y estos dentro de un array. Así que puedo acceder a ellos de la siguiente manera:

```
               val obj= it.get("idMovimiento") as ArrayList<String>
                val obj2 = obj[0] as HashMap<*,*>
                println("======================${it.get("idMovimiento").toString()}")
                println("=========={obj2============${obj2}")
                println("=========obj2[\"talle\"]=============${obj2["talle"]}")
```